# Xubuntu 18.04 suddenly slow booting, not detecting second monitor, bootlooping and occassionally starting in emergency mode

Tags: boot, grub2, nvidia, xubuntu, display

I have an Acer Predator Helios 300 2019 laptop with dual boot for Xubuntu 18.04 and Windows that I have been using for around 3+ years now. Last Friday, my second HDMI monitor suddenly did not work, so I reinstalled the nvidia drivers. I know my monitor works because it shows on my Windows. The strangest part is three times, it seemed to boot quickly and both monitors worked fine like when I rolled back to nvidia driver 450 or when it started on emergency mode with driver 510 (did this twice) but when I shutdown or reboot, it would bootloop, boot very slowly and only detect one monitor again leading me to the same problem. If I start on recovery mode then resume boot, either only the laptop monitor works or the external one. I included journalctl error messages. I am at my wit's end, please help me.

I've tried the following:

- fstab UUIDs look fine
- secure boot is disabled
- xubuntu uses lightdm as a display manager
- Update to latest Nvidia driver (510) then reboot

```
    sudo apt-get remove --purge '^nvidia-.*'
    sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
    sudo apt-get update
```

- Rollback drivers through the "Additional Drivers" tab then reboot, I've tried 450, 470 and I'm on 510 right now.
- ran fsck on my home, swap and root partitions while using a recovery drive
  e.g. "fsck /dev/nvme0n1p6"
- Edited my /etc/default/grub to include the following then sudo update-grub

```
    GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="splash noresume nogpumanager nvidia-drm.modeset=1"
    GRUB_GFXMODE=1920x1080
```

- Result from xrandr (both my displays should be at 144hz)

```
    xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
    Screen 0: minimum 1920 x 1080, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 1920 x 1080
    default connected 1920x1080+0+0 0mm x 0mm
       1920x1080     77.00*
```

- I also tried this [solution](https://superuser.com/questions/997938/how-do-i-figure-out-why-systemctl-service-systemd-modules-load-fails) for slow boot time

1. Result from systemctl --failed

```
      UNIT                         LOAD   ACTIVE SUB    DESCRIPTION                                                                                                                              
    ● systemd-modules-load.service loaded failed failed Load Kernel Modules
```

2. Result from systemctl status systemd-modules-load

```
     ● systemd-modules-load.service - Load Kernel Modules
       Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-modules-load.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
       Active: failed (Result: timeout) since Mon 2022-05-16 02:45:08 PST; 22min ago
         Docs: man:systemd-modules-load.service(8)
               man:modules-load.d(5)
      Process: 340 ExecStart=/lib/systemd/systemd-modules-load (code=killed, signal=TERM)
     Main PID: 340 (code=killed, signal=TERM)
    
    May 15 18:44:01 mypc systemd-modules-load[340]: Inserted module 'coretemp'
    May 15 18:44:01 mypc systemd-modules-load[340]: Inserted module 'arp_tables'
    May 15 18:44:01 mypc systemd-modules-load[340]: Inserted module 'br_netfilter'
    May 15 18:44:01 mypc systemd-modules-load[340]: Inserted module 'ip6table_filter'
    May 15 18:45:31 mypc systemd[1]: systemd-modules-load.service: Start operation timed out. Terminating.
    May 16 02:45:07 mypc systemd[1]: systemd-modules-load.service: State 'stop-sigterm' timed out. Killing.
    May 16 02:45:07 mypc systemd[1]: systemd-modules-load.service: Killing process 340 (systemd-modules) with signal SIGKILL.
    May 16 02:45:08 mypc systemd[1]: systemd-modules-load.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=15/TERM
    May 16 02:45:08 mypc systemd[1]: systemd-modules-load.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
    May 16 02:45:08 mypc systemd[1]: Failed to start Load Kernel Modules.
```

3. journalctl _PID=340 shows no errors
4. systemctl restart systemd-modules-load shows no errors

- Lastly, here is the result of journalctl -p err -xb which I suspect may contain the issue

```
    -- Logs begin at Thu 2020-09-17 16:38:56 PST, end at Mon 2022-05-16 02:59:06 PST. --
    May 15 18:44:01 mypc kernel: Couldn't get size: 0x800000000000000e
    May 16 02:45:08 mypc systemd-udevd[356]: seq 3568 '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0' killed
    May 16 02:45:08 mypc systemd-udevd[356]: seq 4456 '/devices/platform/PNP0C14:03/wmi_bus/wmi_bus-PNP0C14:03/86CCFD48-205E-4A77-9C48-2021CBEDE341' killed
    May 16 02:45:08 mypc systemd-udevd[356]: seq 4440 '/devices/pci0000:00/PNP0C14:00/wmi_bus/wmi_bus-PNP0C14:00/05901221-D566-11D1-B2F0-00A0C9062910' killed
    May 16 02:45:08 mypc systemd-udevd[356]: seq 4429 '/devices/pci0000:00/PNP0C14:00/wmi_bus/wmi_bus-PNP0C14:00/676AA15E-6A47-4D9F-A2CC-1E6D18D14026' killed
    May 16 02:45:08 mypc systemd-udevd[356]: seq 3619 '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.3' killed
    May 16 02:45:08 mypc systemd-udevd[356]: seq 3812 '/devices/system/cpu/cpu9' killed
    May 16 02:45:08 mypc systemd-udevd[356]: seq 3811 '/devices/system/cpu/cpu8' killed
    May 16 02:45:08 mypc systemd-udevd[356]: seq 3809 '/devices/system/cpu/cpu7' killed
    May 16 02:45:08 mypc systemd-udevd[356]: seq 3808 '/devices/system/cpu/cpu6' killed
    May 16 02:45:08 mypc systemd-udevd[356]: seq 3807 '/devices/system/cpu/cpu5' killed
    May 16 02:45:08 mypc systemd-udevd[356]: seq 3613 '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7/1-7:1.0' killed
    May 16 02:45:08 mypc systemd-udevd[356]: seq 3605 '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-5/1-5:1.1/0003:0C45:8006.0004/input/input8' killed
    May 16 02:45:08 mypc systemd-udevd[356]: seq 3577 '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-14/1-14:1.1' killed
    May 16 02:45:08 mypc systemd-udevd[356]: seq 3576 '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-14/1-14:1.0' killed
    May 16 02:45:08 mypc systemd-udevd[356]: seq 3622 '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.1' killed
    May 16 02:45:08 mypc systemd-udevd[356]: seq 3805 '/devices/system/cpu/cpu3' killed
    May 16 02:45:08 mypc systemd-udevd[356]: seq 3804 '/devices/system/cpu/cpu2' killed
    May 16 02:45:08 mypc systemd-udevd[356]: seq 3803 '/devices/system/cpu/cpu11' killed
    May 16 02:45:08 mypc systemd-udevd[356]: seq 3802 '/devices/system/cpu/cpu10' killed
    May 16 02:45:08 mypc systemd-udevd[356]: seq 3800 '/devices/system/cpu/cpu0' killed
    May 16 02:45:08 mypc systemd-udevd[356]: seq 3801 '/devices/system/cpu/cpu1' killed
    May 16 02:45:08 mypc systemd-udevd[356]: seq 3559 '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0' killed
    May 16 02:45:08 mypc systemd-udevd[356]: seq 3560 '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1' killed
    May 16 02:45:08 mypc systemd-udevd[356]: seq 3806 '/devices/system/cpu/cpu4' killed
    May 16 02:45:08 mypc systemd-udevd[356]: seq 3735 '/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input4' killed
    May 16 02:45:08 mypc systemd-udevd[356]: seq 3688 '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3' killed
    May 16 02:45:08 mypc systemd-udevd[356]: seq 3623 '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:16.0' killed
    May 16 02:45:08 mypc systemd-udevd[356]: seq 3621 '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0' killed
    May 16 02:45:08 mypc systemd-udevd[356]: worker [388] failed while handling '/devices/system/cpu/cpu7'
    May 16 02:45:08 mypc systemd-udevd[356]: worker [389] failed while handling '/devices/system/cpu/cpu6'
    May 16 02:45:08 mypc systemd-udevd[356]: worker [397] failed while handling '/devices/system/cpu/cpu8'
    May 16 02:45:08 mypc systemd-udevd[356]: worker [398] failed while handling '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3'
    May 16 02:45:08 mypc systemd-udevd[356]: worker [406] failed while handling '/devices/system/cpu/cpu9'
    May 16 02:45:08 mypc systemd-udevd[356]: worker [407] failed while handling '/devices/system/cpu/cpu5'
    May 16 02:45:08 mypc systemd-udevd[356]: worker [422] failed while handling '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1'
    May 16 02:45:08 mypc systemd-udevd[356]: worker [423] failed while handling '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.1'
    May 16 02:45:08 mypc systemd-udevd[356]: worker [394] failed while handling '/devices/system/cpu/cpu1'
    May 16 02:45:08 mypc systemd-udevd[356]: worker [391] failed while handling '/devices/system/cpu/cpu0'
    May 16 02:45:08 mypc systemd-udevd[356]: worker [392] failed while handling '/devices/system/cpu/cpu4'
    May 16 02:45:08 mypc systemd-udevd[356]: worker [393] failed while handling '/devices/platform/PNP0C14:03/wmi_bus/wmi_bus-PNP0C14:03/86CCFD48-205E-4A77-9C48-2021CBEDE341'
    May 16 02:45:08 mypc systemd-udevd[356]: worker [396] failed while handling '/devices/pci0000:00/PNP0C14:00/wmi_bus/wmi_bus-PNP0C14:00/05901221-D566-11D1-B2F0-00A0C9062910'
    May 16 02:45:08 mypc systemd-udevd[356]: worker [400] failed while handling '/devices/system/cpu/cpu10'
    May 16 02:45:08 mypc systemd-udevd[356]: worker [399] failed while handling '/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input4'
    May 16 02:45:08 mypc systemd-udevd[356]: worker [395] failed while handling '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0'
    May 16 02:45:08 mypc systemd-udevd[356]: worker [402] failed while handling '/devices/system/cpu/cpu3'
    May 16 02:45:08 mypc systemd-udevd[356]: worker [404] failed while handling '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0'
    May 16 02:45:08 mypc systemd-udevd[356]: worker [405] failed while handling '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7/1-7:1.0'
    May 16 02:45:08 mypc systemd-udevd[356]: worker [411] failed while handling '/devices/pci0000:00/PNP0C14:00/wmi_bus/wmi_bus-PNP0C14:00/676AA15E-6A47-4D9F-A2CC-1E6D18D14026'
    May 16 02:45:08 mypc systemd-udevd[356]: worker [412] failed while handling '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.3'
    May 16 02:45:08 mypc systemd-udevd[356]: worker [413] failed while handling '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:16.0'
    May 16 02:45:08 mypc systemd-udevd[356]: worker [414] failed while handling '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-14/1-14:1.0'
    May 16 02:45:08 mypc systemd-udevd[356]: worker [416] failed while handling '/devices/system/cpu/cpu2'
    May 16 02:45:08 mypc systemd-udevd[356]: worker [417] failed while handling '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0'
    May 16 02:45:08 mypc systemd-udevd[356]: worker [418] failed while handling '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-5/1-5:1.1/0003:0C45:8006.0004/input/input8'
    May 16 02:45:08 mypc systemd-udevd[356]: worker [421] failed while handling '/devices/system/cpu/cpu11'
    May 16 02:45:08 mypc systemd-udevd[356]: worker [424] failed while handling '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-14/1-14:1.1'
    May 16 02:45:08 mypc systemd[1]: Failed to start Load Kernel Modules.
    -- Subject: Unit systemd-modules-load.service has failed
    -- Defined-By: systemd
    -- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
    -- 
    -- Unit systemd-modules-load.service has failed.
    -- 
    -- The result is RESULT.
    May 16 02:45:08 mypc kernel: PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key
    May 16 02:45:08 mypc kernel: PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key
    May 16 02:45:08 mypc kernel: PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key
    May 16 02:45:08 mypc mysqld[1403]: 2022-05-16  2:45:08 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 10.4.20-MariaDB-1:10.4.20+maria~bionic-log) starting as process 1403 ...
    May 16 02:45:08 mypc mysqld[1403]: 2022-05-16  2:45:08 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
    May 16 02:45:08 mypc mysqld[1403]: 2022-05-16  2:45:08 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
    May 16 02:45:08 mypc mysqld[1403]: 2022-05-16  2:45:08 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
    May 16 02:45:08 mypc mysqld[1403]: 2022-05-16  2:45:08 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
    May 16 02:45:08 mypc mysqld[1403]: 2022-05-16  2:45:08 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
    May 16 02:45:08 mypc mysqld[1403]: 2022-05-16  2:45:08 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
    May 16 02:45:08 mypc mysqld[1403]: 2022-05-16  2:45:08 0 [Note] mysqld: O_TMPFILE is not supported on /tmp (disabling future attempts)
    May 16 02:45:08 mypc mysqld[1403]: 2022-05-16  2:45:08 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 256M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
    May 16 02:45:08 mypc mysqld[1403]: 2022-05-16  2:45:08 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
    May 16 02:45:08 mypc mysqld[1403]: 2022-05-16  2:45:08 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
    May 16 02:45:09 mypc mysqld[1403]: 2022-05-16  2:45:09 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
    May 16 02:45:09 mypc mysqld[1403]: 2022-05-16  2:45:09 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
    May 16 02:45:09 mypc mysqld[1403]: 2022-05-16  2:45:09 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
    May 16 02:45:09 mypc mysqld[1403]: 2022-05-16  2:45:09 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
    May 16 02:45:09 mypc mysqld[1403]: 2022-05-16  2:45:09 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
    May 16 02:45:09 mypc mysqld[1403]: 2022-05-16  2:45:09 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.20 started; log sequence number 3469035; transaction id 339
    May 16 02:45:09 mypc mysqld[1403]: 2022-05-16  2:45:09 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
    May 16 02:45:09 mypc mysqld[1403]: 2022-05-16  2:45:09 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
    May 16 02:45:09 mypc mysqld[1403]: 2022-05-16  2:45:09 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 220516  2:45:09
    May 16 02:45:09 mypc mysqld[1403]: 2022-05-16  2:45:09 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '127.0.0.1'.
    May 16 02:45:09 mypc mysqld[1403]: 2022-05-16  2:45:09 0 [Note] Reading of all Master_info entries succeeded
    May 16 02:45:09 mypc mysqld[1403]: 2022-05-16  2:45:09 0 [Note] Added new Master_info '' to hash table
    May 16 02:45:09 mypc mysqld[1403]: 2022-05-16  2:45:09 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
    May 16 02:45:09 mypc mysqld[1403]: Version: '10.4.20-MariaDB-1:10.4.20+maria~bionic-log'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  mariadb.org binary distribution
    May 16 02:45:09 mypc kernel: aufs aufs_fill_super:912:mount[1803]: no arg
    May 16 02:45:09 mypc kernel: overlayfs: missing 'lowerdir'
    May 16 02:47:03 mypc lightdm[1846]: PAM unable to dlopen(pam_kwallet.so): /lib/security/pam_kwallet.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    May 16 02:47:03 mypc lightdm[1846]: PAM adding faulty module: pam_kwallet.so
    May 16 02:47:03 mypc lightdm[1846]: PAM unable to dlopen(pam_kwallet5.so): /lib/security/pam_kwallet5.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    May 16 02:47:03 mypc lightdm[1846]: PAM adding faulty module: pam_kwallet5.so
    May 16 02:47:04 mypc lightdm[1985]: PAM unable to dlopen(pam_kwallet.so): /lib/security/pam_kwallet.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    May 16 02:47:04 mypc lightdm[1985]: PAM adding faulty module: pam_kwallet.so
    May 16 02:47:04 mypc lightdm[1985]: PAM unable to dlopen(pam_kwallet5.so): /lib/security/pam_kwallet5.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    May 16 02:47:04 mypc lightdm[1985]: PAM adding faulty module: pam_kwallet5.so
    May 16 02:47:19 mypc spice-vdagent[2363]: Cannot access vdagent virtio channel /dev/virtio-ports/com.redhat.spice.0
    May 16 02:47:19 mypc pulseaudio[2382]: [pulseaudio] backend-ofono.c: Failed to register as a handsfree audio agent with ofono: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.ofono was not provided by any .service files
```

Comment: There is also other 18.04 users https://askubuntu.com/questions/1409391/timed-out-waiting-for-device-problem - could you (since I don't have actually hands-on with the computer) maybe try selecting older kernel from the boot menu (tapping Esc when powering on the machine, right after computer logo)? I'm slightly suspecting there might be a kernel regression in 18.04.

Addition: It's probably this https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1973482

Comment: It's working perfectly, thank you! I'm using 4.15.0-176 now, previously  4.15.0-177.