# Timed out waiting for device problem

Tags: boot, 18.04, disk

EDIT: When running the previous version of the kernel, I don’t get any of these symptoms. It is therefor most likely, that there was some kernel bug introduced.

I had lately experienced some problems with booting my Ubuntu 18.04 machine. The boot lasts a very long time. After it it drops into recovery mode. When I view the logs with `journalctl` i see messages about timeout for *all* my partitions:

```
Timed out waiting for device dev-disk-by\x2duuid-6949\x2dD5D0.device
(...)
Timed out waiting for device dev-mapper-ubuntu\x2d\x2dvg\x2dswap_1.device
(...)
Timed out waiting for device dev-disk-by\x2duuid-57e2cc57\x2d82b7\x2d481f\x2dac0a\x2d1aec849f9db8.device
```

After this series of messages

```
maj 19 10:42:50 POZDL0272 systemd-udevd[654]: seq 3979 '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.5/1-1.5:1.3' killed
maj 19 10:42:50 POZDL0272 systemd-udevd[654]: seq 3739 '/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/INT3403:03' killed
maj 19 10:42:50 POZDL0272 systemd-udevd[654]: seq 3792 '/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/device:11/PNP0C09:00/INT3403:00' killed
maj 19 10:42:50 POZDL0272 systemd-udevd[654]: seq 4026 '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.1' killed
maj 19 10:42:50 POZDL0272 systemd-udevd[654]: seq 4027 '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:16.0' killed
maj 19 10:42:50 POZDL0272 systemd-udevd[654]: seq 3978 '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.5/1-1.5:1.2' killed
maj 19 10:42:50 POZDL0272 systemd-udevd[654]: seq 3977 '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.5/1-1.5:1.1' killed
maj 19 10:42:50 POZDL0272 systemd-udevd[654]: seq 4021 '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:2.0' killed
maj 19 10:42:50 POZDL0272 systemd-udevd[654]: seq 4012 '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-5/1-5:1.0' killed
maj 19 10:42:50 POZDL0272 systemd-udevd[654]: worker [685] terminated by signal 9 (KILL)
maj 19 10:42:50 POZDL0272 systemd-udevd[654]: worker [685] failed while handling '/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/device:11/PNP0C09:00/INT3403:00'
maj 19 10:42:50 POZDL0272 systemd-udevd[654]: worker [690] terminated by signal 9 (KILL)
maj 19 10:42:50 POZDL0272 systemd-udevd[654]: worker [690] failed while handling '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0'
maj 19 10:42:50 POZDL0272 systemd-udevd[654]: worker [696] terminated by signal 9 (KILL)
maj 19 10:42:50 POZDL0272 systemd-udevd[654]: worker [696] failed while handling '/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/device:11/PNP0C09:00/INT3403:01'
maj 19 10:42:50 POZDL0272 systemd-udevd[654]: worker [700] terminated by signal 9 (KILL)
maj 19 10:42:50 POZDL0272 systemd-udevd[654]: worker [700] failed while handling '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.5/1-1.5:1.3'
maj 19 10:42:50 POZDL0272 systemd-udevd[654]: worker [703] terminated by signal 9 (KILL)
maj 19 10:42:50 POZDL0272 systemd-udevd[654]: worker [703] failed while handling '/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/device:11/PNP0C09:00/INT3403:02'
maj 19 10:42:50 POZDL0272 systemd-udevd[654]: worker [704] terminated by signal 9 (KILL)
maj 19 10:42:50 POZDL0272 systemd-udevd[654]: worker [704] failed while handling '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.5/1-1.5:1.0'
maj 19 10:42:50 POZDL0272 systemd-udevd[654]: seq 4034 '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.0' killed
maj 19 10:42:50 POZDL0272 systemd-udevd[654]: seq 4042 '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.2' killed
maj 19 10:42:50 POZDL0272 systemd-udevd[1242]: link_config: autonegotiation is unset or enabled, the speed and duplex are not writable.
maj 19 10:42:50 POZDL0272 systemd-udevd[654]: seq 4060 '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.0/PNP0C09:00/INT3403:00' killed
maj 19 10:42:50 POZDL0272 systemd-udevd[654]: seq 4046 '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0' killed
maj 19 10:42:51 POZDL0272 kernel: intel-lpss 0000:00:15.1: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
maj 19 10:42:51 POZDL0272 systemd-udevd[654]: worker [689] terminated by signal 9 (KILL)
maj 19 10:42:51 POZDL0272 systemd-udevd[654]: worker [689] failed while handling '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.2'
maj 19 10:42:51 POZDL0272 systemd-udevd[654]: worker [699] terminated by signal 9 (KILL)
maj 19 10:42:51 POZDL0272 systemd-udevd[654]: worker [699] failed while handling '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.0/PNP0C09:00/INT3403:00'
maj 19 10:42:51 POZDL0272 systemd-udevd[654]: worker [705] terminated by signal 9 (KILL)
maj 19 10:42:51 POZDL0272 systemd-udevd[654]: worker [705] failed while handling '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0'
maj 19 10:42:51 POZDL0272 kernel: cfg80211: Loading compiled-in X.509 certificates for regulatory database
maj 19 10:42:51 POZDL0272 kernel: cfg80211: Loaded X.509 cert 'sforshee: 00b28ddf47aef9cea7'
maj 19 10:42:51 POZDL0272 systemd-udevd[654]: seq 4061 '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.0/PNP0C09:00/INT3403:01' killed
maj 19 10:42:51 POZDL0272 kernel: i2c_hid i2c-DELL0816:00: i2c-DELL0816:00 supply vdd not found, using dummy regulator
maj 19 10:42:51 POZDL0272 systemd-udevd[654]: seq 4062 '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.0/PNP0C09:00/INT3403:02' killed
maj 19 10:42:51 POZDL0272 systemd-udevd[654]: worker [694] terminated by signal 9 (KILL)
maj 19 10:42:51 POZDL0272 systemd-udevd[654]: worker [694] failed while handling '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.0/PNP0C09:00/INT3403:01'
maj 19 10:42:51 POZDL0272 systemd-udevd[654]: seq 4064 '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3' killed
maj 19 10:42:51 POZDL0272 kernel: input: DELL0816:00 044E:121F as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.1/i2c_designware.1/i2c-8/i2c-DELL0816:00/0018:044E:121F.0007/input/input10
maj 19 10:42:51 POZDL0272 kernel: hid-generic 0018:044E:121F.0007: input,hidraw4: I2C HID v1.00 Mouse [DELL0816:00 044E:121F] on i2c-DELL0816:00
maj 19 10:42:51 POZDL0272 kernel: mei_me 0000:00:16.0: enabling device (0004 -> 0006)
maj 19 10:42:51 POZDL0272 systemd-udevd[654]: worker [702] terminated by signal 9 (KILL)
maj 19 10:42:51 POZDL0272 systemd-udevd[654]: worker [702] failed while handling '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.0/PNP0C09:00/INT3403:02'
```

and:

```
maj 19 10:42:52 POZDL0272 smartd[1552]: DEVICESCAN failed: glob(3) aborted matching pattern /dev/discs/disc*
maj 19 10:42:52 POZDL0272 smartd[1552]: In the system's table of devices NO devices found to scan
```

Despite this I also see the messages about the disks finishing their startup and if I do `exit` the system starts, albeit with some devices not working. It is a little random, which devices are not available, but typically audio and camera are out.

The top problematic services shown by `systemd-analyze blame` are:

```
$ systemd-analyze blame                              
     3min 2.142s dev-loop16.device
     3min 2.131s dev-loop10.device
     3min 2.125s dev-loop19.device
     3min 2.122s dev-loop14.device
     3min 2.119s dev-loop21.device
     3min 2.114s dev-loop9.device
     3min 2.112s dev-loop12.device
     3min 2.111s dev-loop15.device
     3min 2.111s dev-loop25.device
     3min 2.110s dev-loop18.device
     3min 2.102s dev-loop22.device
     3min 2.101s dev-loop20.device
     3min 2.101s dev-loop26.device
     3min 2.099s dev-loop23.device
     3min 2.093s dev-loop8.device
     3min 2.093s dev-loop17.device
     3min 2.088s dev-loop11.device
     3min 2.076s dev-loop24.device
     3min 2.071s dev-loop13.device
     3min 2.064s dev-loop27.device
     3min 2.061s dev-mapper-ubuntu\x2d\x2dvg\x2droot.device
     3min 2.047s dev-loop29.device
     3min 2.045s dev-loop28.device
     3min 1.985s dev-loop30.device
     3min 1.299s dev-loop0.device
     3min 1.289s dev-loop2.device
     3min 1.278s dev-loop1.device
     3min 1.252s dev-loop4.device
     3min 1.249s dev-loop3.device
     3min 1.235s dev-loop5.device
     3min 1.212s dev-loop7.device
     3min 1.211s dev-loop6.device
    1min 30.693s qemu-kvm.service
    1min 30.280s binfmt-support.service
         15.914s docker.service
          6.717s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
```

I already found two possible causes for these timeouts: incorrect fstab and incorrect resume file. However there seems to be no problem with my fstab:

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot was on /dev/nvme0n1p2 during installation
UUID=1a486187-94d5-4633-a4ea-a72f262044be /boot           ext4    defaults        0       2
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during installation
UUID=6949-D5D0  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

With the result of `blkid`:

```
/dev/mapper/nvme0n1p3_crypt: UUID="o7gOG4-SDIz-dc2x-gxLd-e3Wz-Vpiu-gP64XG" TYPE="LVM2_member"
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root: UUID="f3d1ef88-9162-48ec-a4d6-73a31fe38275" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/nvme0n1p1: UUID="6949-D5D0" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI System Partition" PARTUUID="325c6e33-4e72-4b0d-a67d-7b32a9e76504"
/dev/nvme0n1p2: UUID="1a486187-94d5-4633-a4ea-a72f262044be" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="f0cdea26-3b2c-4048-9513-9542ba8066a7"
/dev/nvme0n1p3: UUID="57e2cc57-82b7-481f-ac0a-1aec849f9db8" TYPE="crypto_LUKS" PARTUUID="6a483251-0630-47de-9bda-eb22caa5d3c3"
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1: UUID="d4bed137-e840-4475-b4ed-acb783fe9a1c" TYPE="swap"
```

I also edited `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume` to read:

```
RESUME=none
```

and run `sudo update-initramfs -u` but this didn’t fix my problem.

Is this a hardware issue? Or is there some other possible misconfiguration that might cause this behavior?

EDIT: The output of `lcpci -v` as requested in commente:

```
$ lspci -v
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 08)
        Subsystem: Dell Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: skl_uncore

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 (rev 07) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
        Subsystem: Dell UHD Graphics 620
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 136
        Memory at ee000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
        Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
        I/O ports at f000 [size=64]
        [virtual] Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: i915
        Kernel modules: i915

00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 08)
        Subsystem: Dell Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem
        Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 16
        Memory at ef340000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32K]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: proc_thermal
        Kernel modules: processor_thermal_device

00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
        Subsystem: Dell Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller
        Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 125
        Memory at ef330000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd

00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem (rev 21)
        Subsystem: Dell Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem
        Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 18
        Memory at ef358000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: intel_pch_thermal
        Kernel modules: intel_pch_thermal

00:15.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 21)
        Subsystem: Dell Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
        Memory at ef357000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
        Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci

00:15.1 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #1 (rev 21)
        Subsystem: Dell Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
        Memory at ef356000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
        Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci

00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1 (rev 21)
        Subsystem: Dell Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 137
        Memory at ef355000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: mei_me
        Kernel modules: mei_me

00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 21) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
        Subsystem: Dell Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
        Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 127
        Memory at ef350000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
        Memory at ef354000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
        I/O ports at f090 [size=8]
        I/O ports at f080 [size=4]
        I/O ports at f060 [size=32]
        Memory at ef353000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: ahci
        Kernel modules: ahci

00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev f1) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 122
        Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=0
        Memory behind bridge: ef200000-ef2fffff
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: pcieport
        Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev f1) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 123
        Bus: primary=00, secondary=02, subordinate=02, sec-latency=0
        Memory behind bridge: ef100000-ef1fffff
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: pcieport
        Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f1) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 124
        Bus: primary=00, secondary=03, subordinate=03, sec-latency=0
        Memory behind bridge: ef000000-ef0fffff
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: pcieport
        Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Intel(R) 100 Series Chipset Family LPC Controller/eSPI Controller - 9D4E (rev 21)
        Subsystem: Dell Device 0816
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0

00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)
        Subsystem: Dell Sunrise Point-LP PMC
        Flags: fast devsel
        Memory at ef34c000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=16K]

00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21) (prog-if 80)
        Subsystem: Dell Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio
        Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 255
        Memory at ef348000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=16K]
        Memory at ef320000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=64K]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_soc_skl

00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)
        Subsystem: Dell Sunrise Point-LP SMBus
        Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 255
        Memory at ef352000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
        I/O ports at f040 [size=32]
        Kernel modules: i2c_i801

00:1f.6 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (4) I219-LM (rev 21)
        Subsystem: Dell Ethernet Connection (4) I219-LM
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 129
        Memory at ef300000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=128K]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: e1000e
        Kernel modules: e1000e

01:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS525A PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
        Subsystem: Dell RTS525A PCI Express Card Reader
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 126
        Memory at ef200000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: rtsx_pci
        Kernel modules: rtsx_pci

02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 8265 / 8275 (rev 78)
        Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wireless 8265 / 8275
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 138
        Memory at ef100000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
        Kernel modules: iwlwifi

03:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 5762 (rev 01) (prog-if 02 [NVM Express])
        Subsystem: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 5762
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16, NUMA node 0
        Memory at ef000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
        Memory at ef004000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: nvme
        Kernel modules: nvme
```

Comment: Can you include the output of `lspci -v`? This will list ID and information about your PCI devices, so you can see which devices throw the error: `failed while handling '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.0`

Comment: @ArturMeinild added

Comment: Possibly related question: [Xubuntu 18.04 suddenly slow booting, not detecting second monitor, bootlooping and occassionally starting in emergency mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1408722/xubuntu-18-04-suddenly-slow-booting-not-detecting-second-monitor-bootlooping-a)

Comment: Did `systemd-modules-load.service` fail for you as well? If yes, the problem seems to be related to some kernel modules not loading properly.

Comment: According to systemctl status this service exited successfully.

Comment: Hmm, OK - it was just a suggestion.

Comment: I just had a contact from 18.04 user with similar new problems.. sometimes no boot (to graphical) at all, sometimes taking a long time. Using Thinkpad L380. I checked there are no recent systemd changes, so maybe kernel regression related to ACPI?

Edit: likely this: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1973482

Comment: @TimoJyrinki I was just about to edit the question to add the information, that running the previous version of the kernel fixes it. So yes, probably a kernel regression.